# What is the correct way to design a model and its relations?

Tags: mvc, domain-model, layers

I have the following database models and its properties:

- User (id, role_id, name, email, password)
- Role (id, name, description, active)
- User2Role (user_id, role_id)
- Customer (id, name, user_id)

A User has many roles. 
A Customer is a User. But a User is not allways a Customer (e. g. Admin)

Now, how can i represent it in my domain layer?

**Example 1:**

```
public class User {

    private long userID;
    private List<Long> roleIds;

    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userPassword;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
public class User {

    private long userID;
    private List<Role> roles;

    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userPassword;
}
```

Same goes for customer, should i only save the user-id in customer or create a user object and save the user object in customer?

Comment: Is not Customer a role? In the given model, a Customer can be Admin. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think the `role_id` field in the `User` database model is an error and should be removed.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the hints and advice. @Laiv Customer does have a role, but i cover it already with the relation to User, since Customer is a User.

Answer (score 2):

Because C# (and Java) uses *references,* the code

```
private List<Role> roles;
```

is perfectly valid.

`roles` is a list of `Role` references; you're not storing copies of the original `Role` objects, or even the original `Role` objects themselves.  Rather, the `Role` objects are stored in some arbitrary locations in memory, and the `roles` collection merely stores "pointers" to those objects.

It doesn't cost you anything extra (like additional memory), in other words.

This arrangement allows you to reference the same `role` object in each of several `User` objects.  Unlike your roleID example, it still gives you access to all of the fields in the referenced `role`.